# Problem of dominated convergence theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The prime problem comes from exercise 2.4 of Stein's Real Analysis.

> Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[0,b]$,and
> $$g(x)=\int_{x}^b \frac{f(t)}{t}dt\quad 0<x\le b$$
> Prove that $g$ is integrable on $[0,b]$ and
> $$\int_0^b g(x)dx = \int_0^b f(t)dt$$

To do this,clearly,$g$ is measurable.Then,$\forall \epsilon\in (0,b)$,by Tonelli' theorem,
$$\begin{aligned}|\int_\epsilon^bg(x)dx|&\le \int_\epsilon^b\int_x^b\frac{|f(t)|}{t}dtdx\\&\le\int_\epsilon^b\frac 1 x\int_0^b|f(t)|dtdx\\&=(\ln b-\ln \epsilon)\int_0^b|f(t)|dt\\&\le \infty
\end{aligned}$$
i.e $g\in L^1[\epsilon,b]$.Also , by Fubini's theorem,
$$\begin{aligned}\int_\epsilon^bg(x)dx =\int_\epsilon^b\int_x^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dtdx=\int_\epsilon^b\int_\epsilon^t\frac{f(t)}{t}dxdt=\int_\epsilon^b(t-\epsilon)\frac{f(t)}{t}dt   \end{aligned}$$
My ideal is take $\epsilon \to 0$,then
$$\int_0^b g(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_\epsilon^bg(x)dx$$
Absolutely,we should comfirm this equation is established.I think Dominated covergece theorem should guarantee it.But there is a new problem,for general dominated covergece theorem

> Assume $\forall u,f(x,u)\in L^1({\mathbb{R}^d})$,if
> (i)$lim_{u\to u_0}f(x,u)=g(x)$
> (ii)$|f(x,u)|\le h(x),h(x)\in L^1({\mathbb{R}^d})$
> then,$\int g(x)dx = \lim_{u\to u_0}\int f(x,u)dx$

How do we use this theorem to solve our problem?The parameter is in integral sign and integrand function,but for theorem ,we need to dominate integrand funciton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a  good idea to reduce the proof to the case $f \geq 0$ by considering $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$. In this case you can apply Monotone Convergence Theorem instead of DCT : $(t-\epsilon)$ increases and the interval $(\epsilon , b)$ also increases as $ \epsilon$ decreases to $0$.

Comment: You are right,thanks!